# Why would MERGE in BigQuery cause duplicate records in the destination table sporadically?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working with a data pipeline to move data into BigQuery. I'm copying change data capture information to a staging table in BigQuery. Once there, I use a MERGE statement to copy the most recent CDC records into the main table by either inserting them, deleting them, or updating them.

It's my understanding that this approach should prevent duplicates in the destination table. However, I'm getting the most recent CDC record duplicated twice or more in the destination table for some of the records.

```
DECLARE p_run_id STRING;

DECLARE src_range STRUCT < date_min DATETIME,
date_max DATETIME >;

SET
  p_run_id = 'scheduled__2023-06-28T16:45:00+00:00';

--SET p_run_id='manual__2023-05-02T01:58:55.639096+00:00';
SET
  src_range =(
    SELECT
      STRUCT(
        MIN(date_min) AS date_min,
        MAX(date_max) AS date_max
      )
    FROM (
      SELECT
        MIN(end_time) AS date_min,
        MAX(end_time) AS date_max
      FROM
       dashboard.cdc_assignments
      where
        run_id = p_run_id
      UNION DISTINCT
      SELECT
        MIN(cdc_end_time_original) AS date_min,
        MAX(cdc_end_time_original) AS date_max
      FROM
        dashboard.cdc_assignments
      where
        run_id = p_run_id
  ));

MERGE dashboard.fact_assignments m USING (
  SELECT
    *
  EXCEPT
(row_num)
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
          PARTITION BY delta.assignment_seq_id
          ORDER BY
            delta.cdc_change_id DESC
        ) AS row_num
      FROM
        dashboard.cdc_assignments delta
      WHERE
        delta.run_id = p_run_id
    )
  WHERE
    row_num = 1
) d ON m.assignment_seq_id = d.assignment_seq_id
AND m.end_time >= src_range.date_min
and m.end_time <= src_range.date_max
 
WHEN NOT MATCHED
AND d.cdc_operation IN (2, 4) AND d.status != 'DEL' THEN
INSERT
  (
    assignment_seq_id,
    assignment_id,
    cdc_change_id,
    cdc_commit_date,
    employee_seq_id,
    ....
  )
VALUES
  (
    d.assignment_seq_id                   ,
    d.assignment_id                       ,
    d.cdc_change_id                       ,
    d.cdc_commit_date,
    d.employee_seq_id,
    ....
  )
  WHEN MATCHED
  AND ( d.cdc_operation = 1 OR d.status='DEL' )
  THEN 
    DELETE
  WHEN MATCHED
  AND d.cdc_operation = 4
  AND COALESCE(m.cdc_change_id, b'') < COALESCE(d.cdc_change_id, b'')
  THEN
    UPDATE
    SET
      assignment_seq_id = d.assignment_seq_id,
      assignment_id = d.assignment_id,
      cdc_change_id = d.cdc_change_id,
      cdc_commit_date = d.cdc_commit_date,
      employee_seq_id = d.employee_seq_id,
     ....
```

I have reloaded the data for a specific file into the cdc_assignments and the fact_assignments tables, but during the reload, the data that was previously duplicated was not duplicated again. In total, this happens to about 5% of the records loaded in. We're loading around 600,000 assignments per day so we see maybe 25,000 of these in a day.

I have seen some assignments with 4 CDC records which is fine, but then there will be 2 duplicate copies of the most recent CDC record in the target table.

I have also seen assignments with 2 CDC records which end up as 4 copies of the most recent CDC record.

The assignments in question are all in the same file that is loaded into the cdc_assignments table and then the merge is executed against the content of that file. The assignment is not present in any other files so there is no second job that could be in a race condition with this.

Is the merge statement not the correct way to prevent duplicates from entering the target table? Is the merge not guaranteed to only touch a record once?

Thanks for the help.